# different results :Slope analysis in qgis vs ArcMap

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, terrain, spatial-analysis

I want to make slope analysis on geoTiff. I am using ArcMap and qgis. But i get different results, but both are in degrees. I ArcMap i recive range from 0 to 42 degrees, but i qgis it from 0 to 17 degrees. I ArcMap i use slope function in spatial analysis. Z factor 1.  In qgis i use slope i raster analysis, z factor 1.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Please **edit** your question and include more information about your problem: What versions of each program are you using and what are the respective steps you did for the slope calculation. Where and how do the results differ. Ideally provide some small subsets so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: may be you can load the actual min/max values and compare them with them with the arc map ones

Comment: This seems to be a bit of a knee-jerk post. How much have you researched the potential reason behind the differences? Have you calculated a residual raster to see where the differences are and what magnitude they exhibit? Have you looked at the differences in the applied algorithms? You need do go through due diligence to receive relevant advice.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your results??I think Qgis has "count cut" to min/max values. You can check it through Properties -> Style. That means that Qgis "hides" some values, but you can choose to show you the real range.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158542/same-raster-but-different-min-max-in-arcmap-and-qgis