# What's the default histogram manipulation of QGIS for displaying RGB images?

Tags: qgis, raster, sentinel-2, rgb, histogram

When you open an RGB geotiff (e.g. bands 4-3-2 of Sentinel-2) as raster dataset in QGIS - what histogram manipulation is applied by default? Of course I can look at the min-/max-values, but I'd like to know the underlying formulas/algorithm.

Comment: There seems to be something in the documentation https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html.

Comment: It seems that it's just a standard thresholding, excluding the lowest and the highest 2% of the values in each band, thus keeping the middle 96% of values.

Comment: Default QGIS behaviour is to cut the lowest and highest 2%. This can be changed in the settings - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158542/same-raster-but-different-min-max-in-arcmap-and-qgis/158547#158547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments to my question, indeed the default manipulation is to cut the lowest and highest 2% of the values in each band. However, in addition, a histogram stretch for contrast enhancement is carried out after the cutting. (In MATLAB, for example, this would be realized by `band = imadjust(band);`.)